# Appending inside of $.post nested in jquery.each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

**PLEASE NOTE: I'm not getting any errors, just not functioning the way my logic says it should.**

I'm attempting to create a calendar application, essentially my goal at this stage, is on the $document.load of the calendar page, I wish for it to loop through each day of the calendar (1 month) and for each day, send a request to PHP (AJAX, $.post()), query database, and then append those results onto the element it is currently accessing with the.each() function.

What I want/expect to happen:

I expect the results that are passed back from PHP to be appended onto the current day element it is posting off for.

What does happen:

Unfortunately what seems to be happening, is that the post is done for each element (day in the month) but the append, is only happening once and appending to the last element in the set, although as you can see below, my.append is inside the.each()

Please help guys, I'm not sure how I can make it pause after each post and append to the current element, instead of the last!

CODE LISTING:

HTML:

```
<ul class="days">
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  <li><span>7</span></li>
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>9</span></li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li><span>11</span></li>
  <li><span>12</span></li>
  <li><span>13</span></li>
  <li><span>14</span></li>
  <li><span>15</span></li>
  <li><span>16</span></li>
  <li><span>17</span></li>
  <li><span>18</span></li>
  <li><span>19</span></li>
  <li><span>20</span></li>
  <li><span>21</span></li>
  <li><span>22</span></li>
  <li><span>23</span></li>
  <li><span>24</span></li>
  <li><span>25</span></li>
  <li><span>26</span></li>
  <li><span>27</span></li>
  <li><span>28</span></li>
  <li><span>29</span></li>
  <li><span>30</span></li>
  <li><span>31</span></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".days li").each(function()
    {
        $dayNumber = $(this).text();
        $this = $(this);

        $.post("getShiftsMV.php", {dayNumber:$dayNumber}, function(results)
        {

               $this.append(results);

        });

    });
```

PHP:

```
$shifts = 0;

if($_POST["dayNumber"] != "" )
{
    $day = $_POST['dayNumber'];

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE shift_date = '$day'";

     $run = $con->query($sql);

     if($run->num_rows > 0)
     {
         while($row = $run->fetch_assoc())
         {
             $shifts++;
         }
     }

    if($shifts > 0)
    {

       echo'<span class="label label-success">' . $shifts .'</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo'';
    }

}
```

=========================================================================

EDIT:

Using `$var = "test";` for example, does work, as it will run in the console just fine.

[image: $var being used without error]

Comment: you can not use $ in javascript. $dayNumber must be like var dayNumber etc.

Comment: Sorry man, not Javascript, my bad, its Jquery

Comment: brother $ is worked only for PHP to storing value in variable. If you want to store value in javascript or jquery we have to use var than variable's name Like : var dayNumber .

Comment: same thing, jQuery is Javascript framework, you have to declare your variables properly! if you want to use the $ syntax you can but you still have to put 'var' before it. like `var $someVariable;`

Comment: guys, the variables all work fine, my problem is the append, it even appends fine, just not to the correct element.

I dont mean to be rude at all! just saying, $test = x; DEFINITELY works, been using it for years? try it yourself in the console dev tools, i will try your fix, but im not getting errors, just appending incorrectly.

Comment: you can use variable without var (the variable will global scoped rather function scope in this case), except in use strict mode. $ is also technically valid character for variable name but not recommended since it is used by other library such as jquery or angularjs.

Comment: @JakeMcclay your issue is probably your variable naming, without var your $this is essentially global, and it will get overwritten every loop, which in turn make your result append to the wrong "$this" which is most likely the last one.

Comment: Thank you harry, do you have any idea as to why my append only appends to the last List item? as opposed to appending for each as it goes through the loop?

Comment: you can just use var whatever = $(this), i think it should work fine.

Comment: as an aside, I'm not sure this is a great design. Do you really want 31 separate ajax requests to fire when a whole month is displayed? It might be quite slow to render everything. Why not have your PHP take a date range and return all entries for that whole range? Your JS can work out which day it belongs to and attach it to the right place. FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/) does it like that. Actually, maybe FullCalendar would suit your needs for the front-end part, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, thats seems like a much better approach, and thats for the fullcalendar.io suggestion, my goal though, is to build from scratch, practice rather than getting something done! thank you

Comment: Thanks guys, btw, i understand now about the $test vs var $test, THANKS!!!